# Supported Version for Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, browser

I cannot find specific info about supported browsers for Bootstrap (getbootstrap.com).

What version, except IE, of Chrome and Firefox does Bootstrap support?

Thanks!

Comment: For which version of bootstrap you want to know??

Answer (score 2):

From the Bootstrap Documentation for Version 3:

> Specifically, we support the **latest** versions of the following browsers and platforms. On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 8-11. More specific support information is provided below.

You can see what they are running their tests against [here](https://saucelabs.com/u/bootstrap). Although these are for Version 4 (they dropped IE8 support).

[image]

They support the latest version of Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Internet Explorer, being more prone to issues between versions has support for 8, 9, 10 and 11.

If there was an issue with Firefox version 40. It **technically** isn't supported as it isn't the latest version. But generally speaking you would expect a fix to be applied.